# MPI-IO: write subarray

Tags: fortran, mpi, mpi-io

I am starting to use MPI-IO and tried to write a very simple example of the things I'd like to do with it; however, even though it is a simple code and I took some inspiration from examples I read here and there, I get a segmentation fault I do not understand.

The logic of the piece of code is very simple: each thread will handle a local array which is part of a globlal array I want to write. I create a subarray type using `MPI_Type_Create_Subarray` to do so. Then I just open the file, set a view and try to write the data. I get the segmentation fault during the `MPI_File_Write_All`.

Here is the code:

```
program test
  implicit none

  include "mpif.h"

  integer :: myrank, nproc, fhandle, ierr
  integer :: xpos, ypos
  integer, parameter :: loc_x=10, loc_y=10
  integer :: loc_dim
  integer :: nx=2, ny=2
  real(8), dimension(loc_x, loc_y) :: data
  integer :: written_arr
  integer, dimension(2) :: wa_size, wa_subsize, wa_start

  call MPI_Init(ierr)
  call MPI_Comm_Rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myrank, ierr)
  call MPI_Comm_Size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, nproc, ierr)

  xpos = mod(myrank, nx)
  ypos = mod(myrank/nx, ny)

  data = myrank

  loc_dim    = loc_x*loc_y
  wa_size    = (/ nx*loc_x, ny*loc_y /)
  wa_subsize = (/ loc_x, loc_y /)
  wa_start   = (/ xpos, ypos /)*wa_subsize
  call MPI_Type_Create_Subarray(2, wa_size, wa_subsize, wa_start &
       , MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, written_arr, ierr)
  call MPI_Type_Commit(written_arr, ierr)

  call MPI_File_Open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, "file.dat" &
       & , MPI_MODE_WRONLY + MPI_MODE_CREATE, MPI_INFO_NULL, fhandle, ierr)
  call MPI_File_Set_View(fhandle, 0, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, written_arr &
       , "native", MPI_INFO_NULL, ierr)
  call MPI_File_Write_All(fhandle, data, loc_dim, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION &
       , MPI_INFO_NULL, ierr)
  call MPI_File_Close(fhandle, ierr)

  call MPI_Finalize(ierr)

end program test
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last argument to `MPI_FILE_WRITE_ALL` before the error output argument is an MPI status object and not an MPI info object. Making the call with `MPI_INFO_NULL` is therefore erroneous. If you are not interested in the status of the write operation then you should pass `MPI_STATUS_IGNORE` instead. Making the call with `MPI_INFO_NULL` might work in some MPI implementations because of the specifics of how both constants are defined, but then fail in others.

For example, in Open MPI `MPI_INFO_NULL` is declared as:

```
parameter (MPI_INFO_NULL=0)
```

When passed instead of `MPI_STATUS_IGNORE` it causes the C implementation of `MPI_File_write_all` to be called with the status argument pointing to a constant (read-only) memory location that holds the value of `MPI_INFO_NULL` (that how Fortran implements passing constants by address). When the C function is about to finish, it tries to fill the status object, which results in an attempt to write to the constant memory and ultimately leads to the segmentation fault.

---

When writing new Fortran programs it is advisable to not use the very old `mpif.h` interface as it does not provide any error checking. Rather one should use the `mpi` module or even `mpi_f08` when more MPI implementations become MPI-3.0 compliant. The beginning of your program should therefore look like:

```
program test
   use mpi
   implicit none
   ...
end program test
```

Once you use the `mpi` module instead of `mpif.h`, the compiler is able to perform parameter type checking for some MPI calls, including `MPI_FILE_SET_VIEW`, and spot an error:

```
test.f90(34): error #6285: There is no matching specific subroutine for this generic subroutine call.   [MPI_FILE_SET_VIEW]
  call MPI_File_Set_View(fhandle, 0, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, written_arr &
-------^
compilation aborted for test.f90 (code 1)
```

The reason is that the second argument to `MPI_FILE_SET_VIEW` is of type `INTEGER(KIND=MPI_OFFSET_KIND)`, which is 64-bit on most modern platforms. The constant `0` is simply of type `INTEGER` and is therefore 32-bit on most platforms. What happens is that with `mpif.h` the compiler passes a pointer to an `INTEGER` constant with value of `0`, but the subroutine interprets this as a pointer to a larger integer and interprets the neighbouring values as part of the constant value. Thus the zero that you pass as an offset inside the file ends up being a non-zero value.

Replace the `0` in the `MPI_FILE_SET_VIEW` call with `0_MPI_OFFSET_KIND` or declare a constant of type `INTEGER(KIND=MPI_OFFSET_KIND)` and a value of zero and then pass it.

```
call MPI_File_Set_View(fhandle, 0_MPI_OFFSET_KIND, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, ...
```

or

```
integer(kind=MPI_OFFSET_KIND), parameter :: zero_off = 0
...
call MPI_File_Set_View(fhandle, zero_off, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, ...
```

Both methods lead to an output file of size 3200 bytes (as expected).

Comment: Thanks for this answer! However I still get a serious problem: the written file is 69 Go big, and I cannot figure out why for now. If you have any idea why it behaves like that...

Comment: Did you find out why the output file is so huge? I couldn't find another error in your code besides the misused `MPI_INFO_NULL`.

Comment: No, it is still a wonder to me. I think I will create a new question dedicated to this problem, since it seems to work fine if I use `MPI_File_Seek` instead of `MPI_File_Set_View`.

Comment: I think that I've resolved your problem - see the updated answer.

Comment: Great, thanks! It solve my problem. Unfortunately I cannot upvote twice for your answer, else I would do it.